# Hamachi throw "failed to connect to the engine" error in MacOs M1

Tags: macos, apple-m1, hamachi

I want use Hamachi in my MacBook M1 Ventura 13.1.
When i starting "create a new network" or "join in existing network", i received "failed to connect to the engine" error.

Can i use Hamachi in my Mac?

I tried search information on internet, but not found anything...

Answer (score 1):

hamachi is NOT compatible with M1